# How to add aria-label attribute to view field link?

Tags: views

I'm hoping to add an `aria-label` attribute to a link for one of the fields in a view.

Is there a way to add an `aria-label` attribute field or custom attribute field under Rewrite Results --> "Output this field as a custom link"? If not, any other suggestions?

[image]